# Mapbox iOS: starting a navigation mid-route and skipping one or more wyapoints

Tags: swift4, mapbox, mapbox-gl

When calculating a route from the users location, including a waypoint and naturally a final destionation, how does one detect and skip one or more waypoints in order to stay on-route?

At the moment, when I calculate a route between point A and point B with 2 waypoints, the navigation service, upon restart, redirects me back to waypoint 1 although I just physically passed it. I'd like to know if there is a way to detect and skip it. Bare in mind that this scenario comes from restarting the entire app after, lets say, a break, a midnight rest or a crash.

*Scenario*: we are driving from the Netherlands to Germany, from Amsterdam (NL) through Arnhem (NL) to Frankfurt (DE) and ultimately Berlin (DE). We stop for the night in Frankfurt. In the morning, we'd like to continue our route of 'points of interest' and have it continue from the Frankfurt waypoint. At the moment, when I'd boot the app, it works fine but it redirects me back to Arnhem (NL) before, again, continuing on to Frankfurt (DE).

I'm using Mapbox 4.7 with the latest builds for Navigation and Directions.

```
// userLocation being Amsterdam originally, after a nights rest Frankfurt
NavigationRouteOptions(waypoints: [userLocation, arnhem, frankfurt, berlin], profileIdentifier: .automobile)
```

Anybody got a clue on how to achieve this?

Comment: To do what you need I think you'll need to incorporate Mapbox's 'Mapbox Core Navigation'(if you aren't already) which will give you access to the `RouteProgress` object. This link https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/api/navigation/0.29.0/Classes/RouteProgress.html shows the properties of the object, like remainingSteps and remainingWaypoints, etc.

Comment: Nice, I found that link yesterday, but doesn't do quite what I want. I can however provide an interface in which the user is able to skip an X number of waypoints, though I'd really like it if the app just picks up on it. See, when I would be traveling between Frankfurt and Berlin, I won't be precisely AT the Frankfurt waypoint, thus the app should be albe to determine that I am already passed that point and not calculate a route with that waypoint (and all previous waypoints) in it...

Comment: I haven't used this object myself so I'm guessing a little blind I'm afraid. When you shut the app down for the day, could you save the remaining waypoints as an array and then (say the next day) recalculate the remaining journey, starting at the user's current location and using the (saved) remaining waypoints? Although that still leaves the problem you point out about not being exactly at your interim waypoint when you break your journey.

Comment: That was my eventual thinking as well. We use a external API in combination with local storage, so we can indeed check off achieved checkpoints/waypoints. That might actually be the best way to go about it. If a users, say, restarts the app with a restart on the entire route, I'd still like to give them the power to skip certain waypoints, thus still using your original solution. Thanks for the info @Magnas!